# How map multiple inputText to an array or collection property?

Tags: jsf

I want the user to enter one or more names to the JSF's inputText components.
So I'm thinking of a managed bean like this:

```
public class MyBean {

    private String[] names;

    public String[] getNames() {
        return names;
    }

    public void setNames(String[] names) {
        this.names = names;
    }
}
```

But, how do I map the JSF's inputText components to this array property?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, you need to ensure that the array or collection is preinitialized in the bean, i.e. that it is **never** `null`, for the simple reason because JSF won't do that for you as it doesn't know beforehand how many items you want.

E.g. in `@PostConstruct`.

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    names = new String[3];
}
```

Then, you can *either* just access them by an hardcoded index

```xml
<h:inputText value="#{myBean.names[0]}" />
<h:inputText value="#{myBean.names[1]}" />
<h:inputText value="#{myBean.names[2]}" />
```

*or* use `<ui:repeat>` with a `varStatus` to access them by a dynamic index

```xml
<ui:repeat value="#{myBean.names}" varStatus="loop">
    <h:inputText value="#{myBean.names[loop.index]}" />
</ui:repeat>
```

Do **not** use the `var` attribute like

```
<ui:repeat value="#{myBean.names}" var="name">
    <h:inputText value="#{name}" />
</ui:repeat>
```

It won't work when you submit the form, because the immutable `String` class literally doesn't have a setter for the value (the getter is basically the `toString()` method implied by EL).

#### See also:

- [Using <ui:repeat><h:inputText> on a List<String> doesn't update model values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10780858/using-uirepeathinputtext-on-a-liststring-doesnt-update-model-values)

Answer (score 2):

This how i use using the upper example.

```xml
<c:forEach items="#{cotBean.form.conductor}" varStatus="numReg">
    <ice:panelGroup>
        <ice:selectOneMenu value="#{cotBean.form.conductor[numReg.index].gender}">
        </ice:selectOneMenu>
    </ice:panelGroup>
    <ice:panelGroup>
        <ice:selectOneMenu value="#{cotBean.form.conductor[numReg.index].dob.day}">
        </ice:selectOneMenu>
        <ice:selectOneMenu value="#{cotBean.form.conductor[numReg.index].dob.month}">
        </ice:selectOneMenu>
        <ice:selectOneMenu value="#{cotBean.form.conductor[numReg.index].dob.year}">
        </ice:selectOneMenu>
    </ice:panelGroup>
</c:forEach>
```