# how can i handle undefined number of related inputText in JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

i need to collect homework scores of students in a class. what i have done so far is

1. get the list of student ids
2. using ui:repeat i loop thru the list and for each student id, i

   2a)display an h:inputText whose value is the current student id, then

   2b)to the right of textbox in (2a) above, i display another h:inputText for the teacher to enter the score for that student(for now that value is a dummy variable just to get the page to display).
3. i have a single commandbutton to submit all the data.

For example, if i have 20 students, i would have 20 rows, where each row has two h:inputText, one already containing the current student_id and the other is empty for the teacher to type the score.

How can i collect these values correctly, so that the right student id is linked to the right score.

Note that i cant hardcode the number of textfields cos the number of students in a class can change at any time.

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/6743138/617373 also take a look at http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableEditing.jsf;jsessionid=164B58A98A6016F43E86A846B0DB637D

Comment: thanks Daniel. The first link actually is better for me, but considering that i have  2 sets for each students. how can i use another array to keep the two in sync using index. i mean how can i make sure that when i submit the button, the value in say #myBean.score[0] is the one entered for the first sudent id. cos i need to identify student_id/score entered so i can build a batch sql insert appropriately

Comment: you can have an array (or arraylist) of objects , each object will hold 2 strings for example

Comment: yeaaa, that makes sense. Thanks a ton, 'll try and get back.

Answer (score 2):

Create a model object.

```
public class Score {

    private Long studentId;
    private BigDecimal teacherScore;

    // Getters/setters.
}
```

Have a list of them in some JSF managed bean.

```
private List<Score> scores;
```

Use `<h:dataTable>` to present them.

```
<h:dataTable value="#{bean.scores}" var="score">
    <h:column><h:inputText value="#{score.studentId}" /></h:column>
    <h:column><h:inputText value="#{score.teacherScore}" /></h:column>
</h:dataTable>
<h:commandButton value="Save" action="#{bean.save}" />
<h:messages />
```

That's it.

Comment: thanks u so much BalusC and Daniel too. u guys are the best. your ideas have helped me solve the probem.