# JF2 Dynamic form element doesn't remember input and page refreshes every time I add element

Tags: java, forms, dynamic, jsf-2

I am trying to make a form with options to add rows.  However, after I type in some input and click the add button again, the input I enter disappears.  I'm not sure what is wrong with my code.  In addition, when I click the add button, the page refreshes.  Is there way to stop this page refresh?

Person.java

```
public class Person{

    private List<String> guys = new ArrayList<String>();

public List<String> getGuys() {
    return guys;
}
public void setGuys(List<String> guys) {
    this.guys = guys;

public void addNewItem(){
    guys.add("");
}
}
```

form.xhtml

```
      <h:form>
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">              
          <h:outputText value="Guys: " />
          <h:dataTable value="#{person.guys}" var="men">
            <h:column>
              <p:inputText value="#{men}" />
            </h:column>
          </h:dataTable>
          <h:commandButton name="add" value="Add" action="#{person.addNewItem}" />
        </h:panelGrid>
        <br />
        <h:commandButton name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"></h:commandButton>
  </h:form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided that the bean is placed in the right scope for the functional requirement, the view scope, the only major mistake left is that you're expecting that the `String` class has some magic setter method.

It hasn't. The `String` class is immutable. The following will never work on a `String`:

```html
<p:inputText value="#{men}" />
```

You have 2 options:

1. Create a real model class. You can find complete examples in the following answers:

   - [How to dynamically add JSF components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409053/jsf2-can-i-add-jsf-components-dynamically/3409511#3409511)
   - [Recommended JSF 2.0 CRUD frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180400/recommended-jsf-2-0-crud-frameworks/3180885#3180885)

   ---
2. Set the value by row index instead:

   ```html
   <h:dataTable binding="#{table}" value="#{person.guys}">
       <h:column>
           <p:inputText value="#{person.guys[table.rowIndex]}" />
       </h:column>
   </h:dataTable>
   ```

   *(note: no additional bean property necessary for the table! the code is as-is)*

   This does basically a `person.getGuys().add(table.getRowIndex(), submittedValue)`. I.e. the setter is invoked on the `List` itself, which works perfectly fine. See also the following related answers concerning `ui:repeat`:

   - [Using <ui:repeat><h:inputText> on a List<String> doesn't update model values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10780858/jsf-2-executing-values-in-uirepeat-doesnt-commit-the-values/10784078#10784078)
   - [How map multiple inputText to an array property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6741573/how-map-multiple-inputtext-to-an-array-property/6743138#6743138)

Comment: Thanks! That worked beautifully.   Would you know how to add a new row without refreshing the page? I think I'm supposed to use ajax, but I'm not sure how.  Do I create a not rendered inputText and then render it when I want to add another row?

Comment: Just nest `<f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form"/>` inside `<h:commandButton>`, or replace `<h:commandButton>` by `<p:commandButton update="@form">`. In the future, please ask separate questions as separate questions here.

Comment: Sorry. Next time I'll do that. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You never update your list, you are just adding empty items. You should do something like this:
Person.java (viewscoped)

```
public class Person implements Serializable {
  private List<String> guys = new ArrayList<String>();
  private HtmlDataTable dtGuys;

  public void addNewItem() {
    guys.add("");
  }

  public void addToList(ValueChangeEvent e) {
    guys.set(dtGuys.getRowIndex(), e.getNewValue().toString());
  }

  public String save() {
    System.out.println("saving...");
    for (String item : guys) {
        System.out.println("item= " + item);
    }
    return null;
  }
  //gettes and setters
}
```

form.xhtml

```
<h:form id="frmPrincipal">
  <h:panelGrid columns="2">
    <h:outputText value="Guys: " />
    <h:dataTable value="#{person.guys}" var="men" binding="#{person.dtGuys}" >
      <h:column>
        <p:inputText value="#{men}" valueChangeListener="#{person.addToList}" />
      </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
    <h:commandButton name="add" value="Add" action="#{person.addNewItem}" />
  </h:panelGrid>
  <br />
  <h:commandButton id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" action="#{person.save}"/>
</h:form>
```

Using jsf 2.0.10 and primefaces 3.5

Answer (score -1):

Its because you don't have an scope for that bean, so its request scoped, so when you call the action the bean is created again, you can fix this using a sessionScope or conversationScope